# Wappalyzerってどうしてわかるの？その他

Tags: wordpress

Wappalyzerというwebサービスがありますが、使ってるサーバー、言語などがわかるというのはなんとなく理由が想像できるのですが、CMSなどなぜ分かってしまうのでしょうか？

どのような仕組みで調べているのかご存知の方いましたら教えていただけるとありがたいです。
また、Wordpressを使っていることを調べられたくないなど、情報を隠すことはどうすれば良いのでしょうか？
時折、全く情報が出てこないサイトもあるので、何か対策をしているのかな？
クローラーみたいな技術で調べ上げているとすると、まだ徘徊されてないので情報が表示されていないとか。。。

よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[apps.json](https://github.com/AliasIO/Wappalyzer/blob/master/src/apps.json) にまとめられています。これの読み方は[wikiに説明](https://github.com/AliasIO/Wappalyzer/wiki/Specification)がありますが、ざっと見でも何となく分かりますね。
WordPressの判定部を下記に抜粋しましたが、JavaScriptのトップレベル変数、linkタグ、metaタグ、scriptタグあたりで判定しているようです。

情報を隠すにはカスタマイズして、ここに挙げられているような`WordPress`や`wp-`、`wp.com`といったファイル名や変数名の類いを全て変更することになります。

```json
"WordPress": {
  "cats": [
    1,
    11
  ],
  "env": "^wp_username$",
  "html": [
    "<link rel=[\"']stylesheet[\"'] [^>]+wp-(?:content|includes)",
    "<link[^>]+s\\d+\\.wp\\.com"
  ],
  "implies": "PHP",
  "meta": {
    "generator": "WordPress( [\\d.]+)?\\;version:\\1"
  },
  "script": "/wp-includes/",
  "website": "wordpress.org",
  "icon": "WordPress.png"
},
```

Comment: Wappalyzerがオープンソースということを初めて知りました。
なるほど、アプリごとにapp.jsonに判定ルールを書いてありますね。
何のアプリを使っているかを隠すことの有効性の議論が、セキュリティーの観点からもたまに起こりますが、できれば隠蔽しておきたいものです。
ありがとうございました。